# why does it take so long to delete about 5000 files of very small size (about 100 bytes) on windows 10 64-bit

Tags: windows-10

i was looking for a specific file in windows explorer when i noticed that there are copies of "desktop.ini" file everywhere, i went to the parent folder and ran a windows search for "desktop.ini" and found about 5000 files with the same name at various locations (subfolders), all in the range of about 100-200 bytes, i selected all of them and deleted them, why did it take windows about 2.5 minutes to delete all of those files? assuming an average file size of about 150 bytes, the amount of data to be deleted should be approximately (150*5000) / 1024 kBytes, i.e, about 732 kB. how is windows then able to delete a single file of much greater sizes instantaniously?

Comment: This is not dominated by the file size, locating the file is the expensive operation.  On a spindle drive it is safe to assume it takes about 50 milliseconds, give or take.  It should therefore take 5000 * 0.050 = 250.0 seconds = 4.2 minutes.  You have more give than take, lots more give from an SSD drive.  Deleting these files is a Very Bad Idea, they store metadata about the directory content that Explorer uses.  Visit superuser.com to learn what you've lost.

Answer (score 0):

Delete function is **O(n)**, where n equals the item count, not the file size....

---

*in English:*

your file's aren't "erased".... only it's registration entry is deleted. This depends mostly on the amount of files, not the amount of bytes.

By the way, this is how you can recover "deleted files"; by restoring it's registration entry.